# how can i import this packages (Libraries) in my android application com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

how can i import this packages (Libraries) in my android application

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
```

when i add this in my Application it will show as an error

but this imports are successful

```
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
```

i used Eclipse kepler,
compile with SDK API Google API(Google Inc.)API 19
minimum API level 14
already add Google APIs[Android[4.4] maps.jar
i used Google Maps Android APIv2
in manifest file declare all permissions as follow

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <permission
     android:name="com.example.googlenewmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:name =  "com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.googlenewmap.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and add MapAPI key obtain from https://code.google.com/apis/console
and add into my layout file as follow

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:apiKey = "I have My APIKey here" />
```

i get only grids in my emulator as output and console shows this error
11-28 04:04:57.535: E/MapActivity(1555): Couldn't get connection factory client

i can't understand the full meaning of this error 'coz i am new in android so please guys help me out here.
thankx in advance

Comment: You should remove your APiKey from this question

Answer (score 1):

As to your description

> import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
>   import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

This is not in the right track, which should be

> import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
>   import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

1. Make sure you have import the project "google-play-serviceslib" into Eclipse.
2. Right click your project -> Properties -> "Android" item on the left -> "Add..." a library.

Just like:
[image]

Comment: thankx that solution is working for me, i was added wrong lib project in my workspace.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you haven't import/include/setup the Google Play Services Library.
[This link](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) will provide you with the steps to follow to achieve it. Next You should also check [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api). It is the updated documentation to include Google Maps on your Project. You have already done some of them, but it seems that you missed some things too.